# Smoothing algorithm using integer arithmetic

Tags: c++, c, arduino, integer, bit-manipulation

The following code was taken from an [Arduino tutorial on smoothing](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/Smooth):

```
int smooth(int data, float filterVal, float smoothedVal) { 

  if (filterVal > 1) {
    filterVal = .99;
  }
  else if (filterVal <= 0) {
    filterVal = 0;
  }

  smoothedVal = (data * (1 - filterVal)) + (smoothedVal  *  filterVal);

  return (int)smoothedVal;
}
```

The following statement, took from the same tutorial, got me thinking:

> This function can easily be rewritten with all-integer math, if you need more speed or want to avoid floats.

Fact is I do want to avoid floats and increase speed, but I wonder: how to convert this to integer arithmetic? Bit-banging solutions are a bonus ;o)

Comment: With rational numbers ?

Comment: May be [fixed point math](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/ratio/ratio) comes in handy for your use case.

Comment: @Aderis multiplying and dividing by a power of 2 is often faster, since it can be replaced with shifts.

Comment: There are many types of filtering algorithm, with different responses for different needs. The function returns `int` so I wonder where its input value `float smoothedVal` comes from.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The following article brings some very interesting info on that, if you feel like writing an answer... :o)  http://bleaklow.com/2012/06/20/sensor_smoothing_and_optimised_maths_on_the_arduino.html

Comment: @heltonbiker Hmm, not a link only answer. I'm on my tablet, and writing answers containing bigger amounts of code is hard. Let's see, may be I can give a concise compilation of what's described in the article tomorrow. You may also write one yourself, that's perfectly OK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple technique is scaling up by multiplying the input value with for example `10000` and putting that result in an `int`, do the calculations in `int`, and then scale the output back into a `float` by dividing with the same factor.

In your function you then also need scale up everything with that same factor.

The choice of factor depends on the possible ranges of the values; you want to avoid overflow at the high end, and inaccuracy at the low end.  If you think about it, the factor determines where you put the decimal point: fixed point, instead of floating point.

The factor can be anything, it does not have to be `100`, `1000`, and so on, but `627` is fine too.

If you go down this route, you want to convert as much of your code to `int`, because the conversions described above of course also take time.

To illustrate my point, the following could be it:

```
#define FACTOR 10000  // Example value.
int smooth(int data, int filterVal, int smoothedVal)
{ 
    if (filterVal > FACTOR)
    {
        filterVal = FACTOR - 100;
    }
    else if (filterVal <= 0)
    {
        filterVal = 0;
    }

    smoothedVal = (data * (FACTOR - filterVal)) + (smoothedVal * filterVal);

    return smoothedVal;
}
```

You may need/want to check for overflow, ...

Answer (score 0):

```
//  ------------------------------------------------------------------
//  SMOOTHING WITH INTEGER VARIABLES  (CSHARP)
//  ------------------------------------------------------------------
Int32 Storage;
Int32 SmoothingINT(Int32 NewValue, Int32 Divisor) 
{
    Int32 AvgValue;
    //  ------------------------- Compute the output averaged value 
    AvgValue = Storage / Divisor;
    //  ------------------------- Add to storage the delta (New - Old)
    Storage += NewValue - AvgValue;
    //  -------------------------
    return AvgValue;
}
```

Or

```
' -------------------------------------------------------------------
' SMOOTHING WITH INTEGER VARIABLES  (VbNet)
' -------------------------------------------------------------------
Function SmoothingINT(ByVal NewValue As Int32, ByVal Divisor Int32) As Int32
    Dim AvgValue As Int32
    Static Storage As Int32
    ' -------------------------- Compute the output averaged value 
    AvgValue = Storage \ Divisor
    ' -------------------------- Add to storage the delta (New - Old)
    Storage += NewValue - AvgValue
    ' --------------------------
    Return AvgValue 
End Function
```